# python excel dataorganiser TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

Tags: python, excel, pandas, iterable

I have currently the following dataframes:

1. Excel sheet: (57*9000)
2. Excel sheet: (49*8000)

I have the following functions:

- Locate specific column in each Data-frame
- find the maximum similarity between each cell in excel sheet 1 and excel sheet 2
- Align each match and save them in a 3. excel file

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from difflib import SequenceMatcher


def similar(a, b):
    ratio = SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).ratio()
    return ratio

#Load Batchlog to Data frame

data1 = Batchlog_data = pd.read_excel (r'file1.xlsx')
data2 = Web_data = pd.read_excel (r'file2.xlsx')

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)


order = []
for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    maxima = [similar(row['Name'], j) for j in df2['Name']]
    best_ratio = max(maxima)
    best_row = np.argmax(maxima)

    order.append(best_row)

df2 = df2.iloc[order].reset_index()

pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)

dfFinal=pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)

dfFinal.to_excel("Assembled_Tc2_adjustments.xlsx")
```

Output:

```
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\difflib.py", line 311, in __chain_b
    for i, elt in enumerate(b):

TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

I did try some solutions from previous posts here on stack, but i am still learning python so have not been successfully able to apply the suggestions to my specific function.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED/SOLVED PART

This was solved on another question i had asked here in Stack!

For this particular case the reason it gives the error:

```
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

Is because the dataframes needs to be converted from floats to strings in order for the function to iterate through them.

So right underneath

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

Insert this: (Also remember that df[You_Column_You_want_To_Iterate_Through]

```
df1['Name'] = df1['Name'].astype(str)
df2['Name'] = df2['Name'].astype(str)
```

The following code does:

- It takes the 2 input files and turn them into dataframes
- It will then take a specific Column ( in this case they are both called Name) and use it as its match input
- It takes one name from File 1 and runs through all the names in File 2
- It then takes the name with the highest match and saves their respective row and save them next to each other in the Output File

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

def similar(a, b):
    ratio = SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).ratio()
    return ratio

#Load Batchlog to Data frame

data1 = pd.read_excel (r'File1.xlsx')
data2 = pd.read_excel (r'File2.xlsx')

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

df1['Name'] = df1['Name'].astype(str)
df2['Name'] = df2['Name'].astype(str)

#Function/LOOP
order = []
for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    maxima = [similar(row['Name'], j) for j in df2['Name']]

#best_Ratio=Best Match
    best_ratio = max(maxima)
    best_row = np.argmax(maxima)

#Rearrange new order and save in Output File
    order.append(best_row)

df2 = df2.iloc[order].reset_index()

pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)

dfFinal=pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)

dfFinal.to_excel("OUTPUT.xlsx")  
#Thank you for the help!
```